# CSV export always only exports one row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a pretty simple datatables object. I bind it to an array of objects, specify the data fields and it works. The problem is when I try to implement the CSV export. It always only wants to export the first row of the table. Any ideas?

Here's where my code stands at the moment. And to be sure, I've made sure that the button and select libraries are included but that has made no difference.

```
<table id="tblData" style="display:none;">
    <thead>
        <tr id="trDataTableHeader">
            <th data-s-type="string">Name</th>
            <th data-s-type="string">Address</th>
            <th data-s-type="string">Phone</th>
            <th data-s-type="string">Website</th>
            <th data-s-type="string">Types</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
...
table = $('#tblData').DataTable({
    dom: 'rtB',
    data: tableData,
    columns: [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "address" },
        {
            "data": "phone_number",
            defaultContent: ""
        },
        {
            "data": "website",
            defaultContent: ""
        },
        { 
            "data": "types",
            defaultContent: ""
        },
    ],
    buttons: [{
        extend: "csv",
        text: "Export",
        exportOptions: {
            modifier: { search: "none", selected: false}
        }
    }],
    select: false,
    lengthChange: false,
    sort: false,
    paging: false
});
```

Comment: Can you please share the entire code with datasets as well as CSS and JS you included? So we can play around with that

Comment: CSS has nothing to do with javascript functionality. Furthermore, following best practices, you code CSS against classes, not IDs and there are no classes in the code. The object is a simple javascript object (var thing = {name:"", address: "",  phone_number: "", website: "", types: ""}) with only the 5 properties you see in the code. As you can see in the sample code, every column is a string. If you want to have ALL the javascript includes, you're going to have to go to datatables wesite to download it.

Comment: CSV button for DataTables has some requirements. You can see that from the right side note from https://datatables.net/reference/button/csv that's why I was asking.

And also there has some parameters changed based on datatable js version.

Comment: That looks like a hot mess! Who knows what the plugin is doing?? Try moving the csv functionality out of datatables and convert the json array manually. There are some good c# csv tools out there...CsvHelper is one.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I made an accidental discovery when I removed the column data type specifications. I got an error message that `str.replace` is not a function.

Turns out that the `parseInt` and `parseFloat` base functions were being overridden by another developer on that page and was causing a problem but DataTables was too graceful to tell me.

This is why you don't override base javascript functions unless you absolutely have to.